# How to Create custom control in asp.net with jquery

Tags: custom-controls, asp.net-customcontrol

Please can any body provide the code example. how to embedded jquery datapicker in asp.net textbox.. Mean how do i create this using asp.net control with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having a problem associating a ASP.NET Textbox for use with the [jQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), then this should help:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("<%=Date.ClientID %>").datepicker();
    });
</script>
<div class="demo">
     <p>Date: <asp:TextBox ID="Date" runat="server" /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to do this ..
Embedding JQuery Inside Your ASP.NET Server Side Custom Control.